# IntersectionObserver error when embedding YouTube video in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I've embedded a YouTube video in an iframe on a page in my Chrome extension:

```
<div id="container" class="streamContainer">
    <iframe id="vid" class="streamEmbed" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/prd2RfhF1tM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="false" ></iframe>
</div>
```

The embed was working fine up until a couple weeks ago, but for the last few weeks the embed screen will intermittently not load and instead show a completely black screen. When I opened the console to check for errors, I saw the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Failed to construct 'IntersectionObserver': Unable to get root node in main frame to track.
at new MZ (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player-en_US-vflVlxFvV/base.js:3715:122)
at new g2 (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player-en_US-vflVlxFvV/base.js:3999:112)
at g2.create (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player-en_US-vflVlxFvV/base.js:6995:333)
at Gi.<anonymous> (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vfl-i_LLs/www-embed-player.js:507:269)
at Gi.l.jb (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vfl-i_LLs/www-embed-player.js:507:308)
at Ki (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vfl-i_LLs/www-embed-player.js:505:143)
at Gi.l.oa (https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vfl-i_LLs/www-embed-player.js:498:176)
at https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/www-embed-player-vfl-i_LLs/www-embed-player.js:557:378
```

IntersectionObserver seems to be fairly new, so there doesn't seem to be a lot of information available on this error. Any idea what might be causing it?

EDIT:

manifest.json:

```
{


"manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "FactPopUp",
  "description": "Creates notifications for fact-checking tweets.",
  "version": "2.1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "logo.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": [
        "keys.js",
        "js/alert.js",
        "lib/CryptoJS v3.1.2/rollups/hmac-sha256.js",
        "lib/CryptoJS v3.1.2/components/enc-base64-min.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },

  "content_security_policy": "media-src https://pbs.twimg.com/media/* 'self'; img-src https://pbs.twimg.com/ 'self' data: chrome-extension-resource:;  script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'",

  "permissions": [
    "notifications",
    "activeTab",
    "alarms",
    "fontSettings",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/*",
    "https://stream.twitter.com/*",
    "http://www.politifact.com/*",
    "https://pbs.twimg.com/*",
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ReportersLabDuke/FactPopUp/*",
    "gcm",
    "storage",
    "https://*.servicebus.windows.net/*",
    "management",
    "alarms"
  ], 
  "externally_connectable": {
    "matches": [
      "https://stream.twitter.com/*",
      "http://www.politifact.com/*"
    ]
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "logo.png"
  ]

}
```

Full html of page with iframe:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Debate video player</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: "Segoe UI", "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, sans-serif;
            font-size: 100%;
            margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;overflow: hidden;
        }

        html {margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;}

        #status {
            /* avoid an excessively wide status text */
            white-space: pre;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            overflow: hidden;
            max-width: 400px;
        }

        .streamEmbed {
            width: 100%    !important;
            height: 100%   !important;
        }

        .streamContainer {
            width: 100%    !important;
            height: 100%   !important;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/streamspage.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" class="streamContainer">
        <iframe id="vid" class="streamEmbed" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/prd2RfhF1tM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="false" ></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript running on page with iframe:

```
// JavaScript source code
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = process;
window.onload = function () {
    xhr.open("GET", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ReportersLabDuke/FactPopUp/master/livestream_url", true);
    xhr.send();

}

function process()
{
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    var url = xhr.responseText;
    console.log(url);
    document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].setAttribute("src", url);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more context for where you have the `<iframe>` HTML.  Please provide a *manifest.json*, so we know generally how things are organized. We need to be able to duplicate the problem. Basically, be need a [mcve] which we can use to duplicate the problem in order to investigate.

Comment: Thanks! I've added the html from the page as well as the manifest and the js running on the page. Basically the page is just that iframe taking up the entire page

Comment: The error message shows that the error occurs inside YouTube player. I'd say you can't fix it, let Google know by submitting a bug report.

Comment: I have opened an issue with the Chrome team here, please star it https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=698545